# Virtual host for angular 2 application in apache 2 not working

Tags: apache2, angular2-routing, virtual-hosts

I need to create a virtual host or domain for my angular 2 application.

In brief, i had followed the below steps:

1) Created virtual host file for my site (From: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts)

2) build the project in prod mode: ng build --prod (got dist folder)

These are my settings files from the above tutorial link that i had made in my server:

**etc\apache2\sites-available\mydomain.com.conf**

```
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Angular2/path_to_my_app

<Directory /var/www/html/Angular2/path_to_my_app>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride all
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
 </Directory>
```

In my windows host file added an entry to my site to map the ip

**C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts**

```
10.*.*.*    mydomain.com
```

In my server etc/host added an entry

**etc\hosts**

```
127.0.0.1   mydomain.com
```

In my angular 2 application's src folder (where index.html resides)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /var/www/html/Angular2/path_to_my_app
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

And in the same folders index.html:

```
<base href="/var/www/html/Angular2/path_to_my_app">
```

**My package.json has:**

```
"start": "ng serve --host mydomain.com"
```

The created domain seems to load (hopefully, assuming deep links works), but when i hit **mydomain.com**, i get the angular2's folder structure view in my browser, not my site loaded

[image]

Where is my configuration incorrect.

Do i need to configure any other file in angular 2. If so which?

Comment: You shouldn't use <ifModule> in this config. You want an error if mod_rewrite is not enabled so you can go and enable it.

Answer (score 0):

ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Angular2/path_to_my_app/src

in etc\apache2\sites-available\mydomain.com.conf, append /src to DocumentRoot